# Subracting values from one column based on another dataframes column

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame([['abc', 10], ['def', 20], ['hij', 30], ['loi', 5]], 
                    columns=['id', 'val'])
```

`df_1`

```
id      val

abc     10
def     20
hij     30
loi     5
```

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame([['abc', 5], ['a11', 5], ['pol', 7], ['hij', 3]], 
                    columns=['id', 'val'])
```

`df_2`

```
id      val

abc     5
a11     5
def     30
pol     7
hij     3
```

I want to subract values from `df_1` column `val` by the corresponding value in `df_2` column `val` so that the result would look like this:

```
id      val

abc     5
def     -10
hij     27
loi     5
```

I tried using `.groupby()` but nothing worth of value came out, I believe there is an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by `id` by `Series` from `df_2` and then subtract by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) with specified `fill_value=0` for same value if no match:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame([['abc', 10], ['def', 20], ['hij', 30], ['loi', 5]], 
                    columns=['id', 'val'])

df_2 = pd.DataFrame([['abc', 5], ['a11', 5], ['def', 30],['pol', 7], ['hij', 3]], 
                    columns=['id', 'val'])

df_1['new'] = df_1['val'].sub(df_1['id'].map(df_2.set_index('id')['val']), fill_value=0)
print(df_1)
    id  val   new
0  abc   10   5.0
1  def   20 -10.0
2  hij   30  27.0
3  loi    5   5.0
```

**Details**:

```
print(df_1['id'].map(df_2.set_index('id')['val']))
0     5.0
1    30.0
2     3.0
3     NaN
Name: id, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
df_r = pd.merge(df_1,df_2, on = 'id', how = 'left').fillna(0)
df_r['val'] = df_r['val_x'] - df_r['val_y']
df_r = df_r[['id','val']]
df_r
id  val
0   abc 5.0
1   def -10.0
2   hij 27.0
3   loi 5.0
```